# pandas apply for row

Tags: python, pandas, function

I'm having a problem with function DataFrame.apply().

I need to get row as argument, but it gets elements of each row separately in each call.

[data frame here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90GxA.png)

```
def parser(row):
  feature1 = row['feature1']

  """
  do some computations with feature1
  """

  feature = answer_from_previous_steps
  label = row['label']

  return [feature, label]

temp = df.apply(parser, axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of your df?

Comment: do you mean you want to pass the entire column 'feature1' instead of just an element of 'feature1' in each call?

Comment: I want to pass each object to my function and in my function it should be like an  array or dictionary : {'feature1': 'background.wav', 'label': 'background'}. And after that I wanna extract it from this array.

Comment: I see. The input variable 'row' inside the function 'parser' should already be what you want, trying to put in some print statements and check.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. I was confusing due wrong logs in my code

Comment: post your solution instead. It may help someone later.